# MySQL JSON_OBJECT() datetime format

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a JSON structure by using a JSON_OBJECT and JSON_ARRAY functions in my select query. The problem I have is with the format in which datetime columns are returned in the formatted JSON result.

For example I have a table **titles**

```
id (INT), title (VARCHAR), created_at (DATETIME)
```

and a row would be like this

```
1,"Title 1","2019-02-03 12:13:14"
```

If I now do the following query

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('title',title,'created_at',created_at) AS title_json FROM titles WHERE id = 1;
```

I will get the resulting **title_json** column as:

```
{
    "title": "Title 1",
    "created_at": "2019-02-03 12:13:14.000000"
}
```

I would like to have the datetime values returned in the standard **YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss** format, without the trailing zeroes.

Is this possible?

I have looked through the JSON_OBJECT documentation but couldn't find any clues to this mystery. I'm thinking the format used might be defined somewhere in the server/database settings. The ideal solution for my case would be to optionally set the desired format in individual queries themselves.

I'm using:
Server: MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Version: 5.7.24

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('title',title,'created_at',
                    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%c-%d %H:%i:%s")) AS title_json 
  FROM titles 
 WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Use '%Y-%m-%d %T' for leading zero's